# Externalizing a datasource for creating content to be used on ios app

Tags: iphone, sql, ios, sqlite

I hope that my title is descriptive enough. I am planning on creating a directory application for my town however I would like to to be a fully offline experience.

The idea would be to offer businesses a yearly subscription for listing their business in the directory.

My concept would be to create a web interface where they can pay for their subs and then enter all of the information into a their profile listing that would then be saved into a sql db.

I am wondering if it is then possible to take this sql database and then use it in the application by saving it into the application directory some how.

Basically my question is how could I do something like this? what is the best way to get them to enter their own information then me somehow build that database into the application?

Its not certain that I will even end up doing this but I am just really intrested in how to generate my own content for application like this that I can then use strictly offline.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion , need to create some web application that provide information each specific client and client need to sync some update information with server and do caching.

If there is no need to update , use your cache . and If there are something to update . try to decide what is need to update and show them.

hope it helps you

Comment: Yea I came to this conclusion also, However I need the app to be stricktly offline. So I was thinking maybe there is a way to propagate the sqlite database of the app with the database created by the clients from the web interfaces database before submission to the app store? Have you ever heard of anything like this being done? Thanks for your original answer :P

Comment: propagate the sqlite database, sound interesting! . but in common solution, I recommend you to encode your database with JSON encoding and send them over the internet to your web server and decode them. Good luck C.Johns !